# Is $x^{\frac 12}$ the same as sqrt(x)

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

maybe this question is very simple and clear and trivial to everbody.

but right now i'm not sure.

the equotation

$$ x^\frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{x} $$ is only true whenever $ x \geq 0 $ right?

the square root is only defined for positive numbers in "real numbers".

so whats about

$$ x^{2^\frac{1}{2}} = x = \sqrt{x^2} $$

if x would be negative, this equotation wouldn't be true. So my question is, when is it allowed to multiply powers, and when not?

The question is, is the square root always $x^{\frac 12}$ and only defined in positve numbers, or is it only allowed to $x^{\frac 12} = \sqrt{x}$ whenever we are in positive numbers?

Comment: If the power and root are not both even, then their order is interchangeable. Otherwise, we may run into problems if we allow the base to be negative.

Comment: I'd say that it depends on your convention of notations. In complex analysis non-integer powers are, in fact, multivalued functions. In real analysis $\sqrt{}$ is defined only on $\Bbb R_+$. As long as there's no ambiguity to conventions, both notations $^{1/2}$ and $\sqrt{}$ are interchangeable.

Comment: ok but when its interchangeable then sqrt(x^2) and x are not the same functions? sqrt(x^2) if i take -2 this is 2 and if it would be just it would stay -2. U know where i'm going?

Comment: We have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: so there is no generelization? everytime I need to think about whats inside my square root? I am not much smarter right now..