# Definition of rational exponents

Tags: soft-question, exponentiation

My question is really simple. I've already found a definition of $a^{1/2}=\sqrt{a}$, whenever $a$ is a positive real number. Are there other authors who define as $a^{1/2}=\pm\sqrt{a}$?

**EDIT**

My definition of $\sqrt a (a>0)$ is the standard one. The positive solution of the equation $x^2-a=0$.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by $\sqrt a$? Where is $a$? It looks weird that if you _have_ unambiguously defined square root (which happens for positive reals, for example) that you wouldn't define $a^{1/2} = \sqrt a$. Remember that the point is to still have formulas $a^{x+y} = a^xa^y$ and $(a^x)^y = a^{xy}$ work.

Comment: @Ennar see my edit please.

Comment: Most analysts (if not all) will agree with your definition, because we want sqrt() to be a map. However an applied mathematician will be quick to add a +/- there when the analysts aren’t looking

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite thank you for your comment. Why would an applied mathematician add a $\pm$ sign?

Comment: As long as we are being ambiguous, *which* value is being positive or negative?  Is $\sqrt{2}$ positive or negative?  If it can be either, what does $\pm \sqrt{2}$ mean?  Couldn't it mean $+\sqrt{2}$ whenever $\sqrt{2} > 0$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ whenever $\sqrt{2} < 0$.  Ambiguity adds ambiguity and seldom makes anything clearer.

Comment: @fleablood $\sqrt 2$ is positive. I'm using the standard definition of $\sqrt2$ which is the positive solution of the equation $x^2-2=0$.

Comment: See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499861/is-x-frac-12-the-same-as-sqrtx?rq=1)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thank you, the comments of this question helped me.

Comment: In real/complex analysis, one never should add $\pm$. However, in field theory, $\sqrt{x}$ is often used to denote **one** square-root of $x$ in some suitable field extension. In general, there is no way to distinguish the two square-roots of an arbitrary element in an arbitrary field extension, because there is a field automorphism on the extension that maps the square-root to its negation. This is the same reason that $\sqrt{-1}$ cannot be 'chosen' uniquely.

Comment: My point is why show $\sqrt{\cdot}$ be "standard" and positive and $\cdot^{\frac 12}$ be multiple?  Intuitively is seems to me that we should define $\sqrt{2} = \pm 2^{\frac 12}$ if anything.  But it's arbitrary and silly.